# ActionView::Template::Error (PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR: column “user_id” does not exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

I deployed my project on heroku.

crackeryourwardrobe.heroku.com is my website.

When I click facebook login, I'm getting this error in heroku logs

```
PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "user_id" does not exist
SELECT "products".* FROM "products"  WHERE (user_id = 1)
```

my view.rb

```
<% if session[:user_id] %>
  <% @account_products.order(created_at: :desc).in_groups_of(3) do |product_group| %>
    <div class = "row">
      <% product_group.compact.each do |product| %>
        <div class="col-md-4">
```

products.rb
    class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
        has_many :line_items, dependent: :destroy
        has_many :wardrobe_item, dependent: :destroy
        mount_uploader :item, ItemUploader 
    end

wardrobe_item.rb
    class WardrobeItem < ActiveRecord::Base
        belongs_to :product
        belongs_to :user
    end

user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :wardrobe_items, dependent: :destroy
```

database.yml

```
default: &default
  adapter: sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

development:
  <<: *default
  database: db/development.sqlite3

test:
  <<: *default
  database: db/test.sqlite3

production:
  <<: *default
  database: db/production.sqlite3
```

schema.rb

```
  create_table "products", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.text     "brand"
    t.string   "image_url"
    t.decimal  "price"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string   "item"
    t.integer  "user_id",    limit: 255
```

product.rb

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :line_items, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :wardrobe_item, dependent: :destroy
    mount_uploader :item, ItemUploader 

end
```

wardrobe_item.rb

```
class WardrobeItem < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :product
    belongs_to :user
end
```

schema.rb

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20150310085128) do

  create_table "line_items", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "product_id"
    t.integer  "cart_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.integer  "quantity",   default: 1
  end

  create_table "products", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.text     "brand"
    t.string   "image_url"
    t.decimal  "price"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string   "item"
    t.integer  "user_id",    limit: 255
  end

  create_table "stores", force: true do |t|
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "users", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "provider"
    t.string   "uid"
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "oauth_token"
    t.datetime "oauth_expires_at"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.integer  "cart_id"
    t.integer  "wardrobe_item_id"
  end

  create_table "wardrobe_items", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "product_id"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
```

I don't know how to solve it... help.....please...

Comment: Have you run `heroku rake db:migrate`?

Comment: May be the specific migration is missed.Try running `heroku rake db:migrate:up VERSION=your_migration_file_version`.

Comment: ActiveRecord::UnknownMigrationVersionError: 

No migration with version number 20150310075303

Comment: also, I added migration , and I commit & deploy heroku I received

Comment: Untracked files:
 db/migrate/20150310075303_change_user_id_type_in_products.rb
 db/migrate/20150310085128_add_wardrobe_item_id_to_users.rb
 public/uploads/product/item/21/

Comment: I migrate succed, and I received PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "user_id" of relation "products" does not exist
: ALTER TABLE "products" ALTER COLUMN "user_id" TYPE integer

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because User model and Product model is not thoroughly connected.

In User model, add up this code

user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :wardrobe_items, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :products, through: :wardrobe_items # this is code
```

it would make your connection to product, through user :)

Comment: I still received error "PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "user_id" of relation "products" does not exist
: ALTER TABLE "products" ALTER COLUMN "user_id" TYPE integer"

Comment: .. I added my other model.rb

Comment: can you give me full schema.rb and user.rb and product.rb and wardrobe_items.rb?

Comment: I added my schema.rb . and Thank your replies

Comment: 1. Delete user_id from product
2. Check your associativities in User, Product, Wardrobe